# sending email in vb.net in HTML formatted page

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I made email form in vb.net it works but i need to send a mail using html format which i made that also works but when i receive mail the value written in text box is not coming in mail. what is problem in this?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class Form
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub submit_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submit_button.Click
        SendHTMLMail()
    End Sub
    ' Method Which is used to Get HTML File and replace HTML File values with dynamic values and send mail 
    Public Sub SendHTMLMail()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(Server.MapPath("html.html"))
        Dim readFile As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim myString As String = ""
        myString = readFile
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Company_Name$$", "Company_Name")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Contact_Person_Name$$", "Txt_ContactPerson.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Contact_Person_Mobile_No$$", "Txt_Contact_No.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Telephone_No$$", "Txt_TelNo.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Email_Id$$", "Txt_Email.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Registered_Address$$", "Txt_Address.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Year_Of_Commencement_Of_Business$$", "Txt_CommenceYear.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Income_TAX_PAN_No$$", "Txt_IncomeTax.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$CST_No$$", "Txt_CSTNo.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$VAT_TIN_No$$", "Txt_VatNo.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Type_Of_Business_Entity$$", "RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Full_Details$$", "")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Business_History$$", "Txt_BusinessHistory.Text")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$No_Of_Employees$$", "Txt_NoOfEmployees.Text ")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$Annual_Turnover$$", "")
        myString = myString.Replace("$$References$$", "")

        Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()
        MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("test@eternalbs.com", "Eternal")
        MyMailMessage.To.Add("test@eternalbs.com")

        MyMailMessage.Subject = "Eternal"
        MyMailMessage.Body = myString.ToString()
        MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True

        ' Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient()
        SMTPServer.Host = "208.91.198.227"
        SMTPServer.Port = 587

        SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@eternalbs.com", "admin123")
        'SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
        Try
            SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage)
            Response.Write("Successfull")

        Catch ex As SmtpException
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Based only on the above, you are **not** obtaining said `Text` values of said/any control. e.g. `"Txt_ContactPerson.Text"`

Comment: u just need to remove the double comma "txtboxvalue.text" to get the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For receving the value of any textbox which user has inserted, the value must not be in double  inverted commas. In the SendHTMLmail() function, the second parameter where you want the textbox value to be captured, u just need to remove the double inverted commas

```
   myString = myString.Replace("$$Contact_Person_Name$$", Txt_ContactPerson.Text)
```

Try this for every textbox whose value u want to capture. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thakyou Nadeem. It's Solved.